# Multidimensional Arrays Ambiguous Reference to Members

Tags: ios, swift, multidimensional-array, swift2

The following code used to work, but now when I try and use the code I'm getting an error stating, "Ambiguous reference to member 'append'". Any ideas?

```
var allInfo: Array = [[String]]()

let Dogs : Array = ["Border Collie","Doberman", "German Shepherd"]

let Cats : Array = ["Top Cat","Tom"]

allInfo.append(Dogs)
allInfo.append(Cats)
```

I've changed the name of the allInfo variable to myPets to see if it that was the problem and updated to Xcode 7.1.1 but still getting the following error. Although it works in playground. Very frustrating.

[image]

Comment: This works fine in playground, Xcode 7.1.

Comment: Strange? I can't get the code to compile in a ViewController.

Comment: Compiles fine this end too

Comment: Tests fine in a view controller.

Comment: "Ambiguous reference to member 'append'" means that compiler is not sure about type. try define you type (don't let the compiler to infer the type from context).var myPets: Array<Array<String>> = []

Comment: restarting Xcode could be helpful ...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all the support. I got this working by explicitly adding the type of each array as follows:

```
let Dogs : Array<String> = ["Border Collie","Dobermann", "German Shepherd"]
```

And I had to remove the : Array from my multidimensional arrays like so:

```
var myPets = [[String]]()
```

I don't know if this is an Xcode bug but hopefully my answer may help others in our community.

[image: image of screen output]

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a different definition of either the `allInfo` variable or the elements you are adding. Make sure you do not have duplicates of those.